# Relativa subfrazo kun «kie» kiu ne temas pri loko

Tags: word-usage

En la angla, oni povas uzi la vorton *where* por enkonduki subfrazon kiu precizigas la situacion de la ĉeffrazo, eĉ se ĝi ne precizigas la lokon. Ekzemple:

> Cycling accidents where the cyclist wasn’t wearing a helmet have increased.

Ĉu eblas fari la saman aferon en esperanto per la vorto *kie*? Ekzemple:

> Biciklaj akcidentoj kie la biciklistoj ne portis kaskon plioftiĝas.

Aŭ ĉu necesas elekti alian vorton? Kiel *en kiu* aŭ *dum kiu*, aŭ mi ne scias…

Comment: Intuicie mi diras, ke uzo de "kie" tiel estas anglismo. Mi serĉis en Tekstaro "akcidento(j)/evento(j)/okaz(aĵo(j) kie", sed trovis neniun taŭgan.  Ankaŭ kun "en kiu" donas nur ege malmultajn trafojn. Do ŝajnas, ke oni ankaŭ ne konstruu tiel. Bona demando!

Comment: Parenteze, la sama afero funkcias ankaŭ en la franca per la vorto «où», do eble ĝi ne estas nur anglismo.

Answer (score 3):

Oni povas uzi `kiu` por tiaj rektaj priskriboj. Detala klarigo troveblas en [PMEG - rilata kiu](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/kiu_kio_kies/kiu.html). La ekzemplo tie:

```
La fera bastono, kiu kuŝis en la forno
```

Ĉi tie `kiu` prenas la lokon de la substantivo, do, se vi havas du jenajn frazojn:

*Plioftiĝas biciklaj akcidentoj*

kaj

*en la akcidentoj biciklistoj ne portis kaskon*

La rezulto estus:

*Plioftiĝas biciklaj akcidentoj, en kiuj biciklistoj ne portis kaskon*

En PMEG troviĝas ankaŭ [*aliaj rilataj ki- vortoj*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/aliaj_ki-vortoj.html) kaj aparta klarigo pri [*rilata kie*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/aliaj_ki-vortoj.html#i-js7), kiu estas loka kaj [*rilata kiam*](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/rilataj/aliaj_ki-vortoj.html#i-3i3) kiu estas tempa.

Comment: Vi pravas. Estas pli bone stile ne havi tiel longan rektan priskriban subfrazon meze de la ĉeffrazo.

Answer (score 2):

"kiam" (when) is a neat substitute for "where" in this context:

where money is concerned - kiam temas pri mono;

More examples are at https://eo.wiktionary.org/wiki/Aldono:Vortaro_angla-Esperanto_w#WH

Comment: Kvankam `kiam` bonas, en tiu frazo pri mono [`se`](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/subfrazoj/se.html) («en la okazo, kiam») estus eble pli trafa.

Answer (score 2):

Mi ne malkonsentas kun la aliaj respondoj pri tio, ke estus pli logike uzi alian konjukcion, tamen se oni konsideras Zamenhofon bona modelo, ne malfacilas trovi ekzemplojn de li “kie” li uzas *kie* tiel:

Zamenhof, Dua Libro de l’ lingvo internacia

> La voĉdonon mi proponis sole por tio, ke al la afero povu esti altiritaj per unu fojo tutaj amasoj da homoj, ĉar mi scias, ke preni ian laboron, eĉ la plej malgrandan, ne ĉiu konsentos, sed helpi aferon tre utilan, **kie** estas postulata nek laboro, nek mono, – ne multaj malkonsentos, tiom pli, se troviĝos memorigantoj.

> Oni devas memori, ke ĉiu lingvo servas por esprimi niajn pensojn, sed ne por senpense traduki el aliaj lingvoj; oni devas tial peni esprimadi siajn pensojn per la jam estantaj vortoj kaj kreadi novajn vortojn nur tie, **kie** ĝi estas efektive necesa, – kaj tiam la vortoj nove kreataj estos nur malofte disĵetitaj inter la multo da vortoj jam konataj kaj povos facile aliĝi al la lingvo kaj riĉigi ĝin ne perdigante ĝian unuformecon.

> En tiaj okazoj, **kie** kelka libereco alportas al ni nenian malutilon, kial ni devus senbezone nin malliberigi?

PIV havas rimarkon pri tia Zamenhofa uzo de *kie*:

> Rim. Z. iufoje uzas kie anst. «en kiu(j)», por faciligi la frazon: *artikoloj, kie estis videble, ke la aŭtoroj […]; en tiaj okazoj, kie vi ne scias, ĉu […].*

Eble per tio oni povas konkludi ke tia uzo estas Zamenhofa sed tamen malrekomendinda.

Comment: Ekzakte *"Zamenhofa sed tamen malrekomendinda"*. Ankaŭ li estis influita de naciaj lingvoj.... Ekzemple, kontrolu la (dubindan) uzon de [ki-vorto + ajn](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/e-vortecaj_vortetoj/ceteraj/ajn.html).